# How to create and configure Command objects from a dynamic context with variable (number of) arguments?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, configuration, command-pattern

SO! I've reached an impasse regarding code-design. Here's the scenario.

I am required to either copy, move or delete files. OK, sure, no problem. I can easily write it like this.

```
public class SimpleFileManager {
    public void copy(String sourcePath, String targetPath) { ... }
    public void move(String sourcePath, String targetPath) { ... }
    public void delete(String filePath) { ... }
}
```

and call it from a client code in a manner like this, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    fileManager.copy(x, y);
    ...
}
```

However, a request arises that some particular POJOs which have the FileManager reference perform specific operations, depending on some configuration. The actual specification of which POJO instance should do what is contained in config.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    InvokerPojo invokerPojo1 = new InvokerPojo(invokerPojo1Config, fileManager); // this config tells it to copy files only
    InvokerPojo invokerPojo2 = new InvokerPojo(invokerPojo2Config, fileManager); // this config tells it to move files only
    InvokerPojo invokerPojo3 = new InvokerPojo(invokerPojo3Config, fileManager); // this config tells it to delete files only
}
```

So, FileManager provides the functionality to do actual operations, while InvokerPojo simply invokes and delegates those methods based on config.

However, I do not want to be coupled to FileManager, because, for example, I may find some library that provides the same functionality but is much better than mine.

So, I was thinking something like this:

```
public interface FileManagerDelegator {
    void copy(String sourcePath, String targetPath);
    void move(String sourcePath, String targetPath);
    void delete(String filePath);
}

public class MyFileManagerDelegator implements FileManagerDelegator {
    private SimpleFileManager simpleFileManager;

    void copy(String sourcePath, String targetPath) { // delegate to simpleFileManager }
    void move(String sourcePath, String targetPath) { // delegate to simpleFileManager }
    void delete(String filePath) { // delegate to simpleFileManager }
}

public class ComplexFileManagerDelegator implements FileManagerDelegator {
    private ComplexFileManager complexFileManager;

    void copy(String sourcePath, String targetPath) { // delegate to complexFileManager }
    void move(String sourcePath, String targetPath) { // delegate to complexFileManager }
    void delete(String filePath) { // delegate to complexFileManager }
}

public interface Command {
    void execute();
}

public class CopyCommand() {
    private FileManagerDelegator delegator;
    String sourcePath;
    String targetPath;

    void execute() {
        delegator.copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }
}

public class MoveCommand() {
    private FileManagerDelegator delegator;
    String sourcePath;
    String targetPath;

    void execute() {
        delegator.move(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }
}

public class DeleteCommand() {
    private FileManagerDelegator delegator;
    String filePath;

    void execute() {
        delegator.delete(filePath);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    Command c = getCommand(context);
    c.execute();
    ...
}
```

Now, the problem is in actually creating that particular command, because I do not want to know which command is being created. All I know is there is info in context that creates it.

I was thinking about having a factory that would create the appropriate Command from context.

The main issue arises in number of parameters for command.
If the only operations that existed were copy and move, then it would have been easy

```
public interface Command {
    void execute(String a, String b);
}
```

However, since there is a delete operation which takes only one, then I'd either have to have to ignore the other argument in the call or add another method to interface, and I consider both to be bad.
I also don't want to send a variable number of arguments like this:

```
public interface Command {
    void execute(String ... args);
}
```

because it's just a bit prettier version of this beforemention bad design.

So, would a factory based on context be a bit more cleaner, in a way that my client code doesn't know which operation is being called, and on which receiver:

Example of 2 contexts:

```
Context copyContext = new Context();
copyContext.set("OPERATION", "COPY");
copyContext.set("sourcePath", sourcePath);
copyContext.set("targetPath", targetPath);

Context deleteContext = new Context();
deleteContext.set("OPERATION", "DELETE");
deleteContext.set("filePath", filePath);
```

And then, in the factory, I could do something like this:

```
Command getCommand(FileManagerDelegator delegator, Context context) {
    String operation = context.get("OPERATION");

    if (operation.equals("COPY")) {
        String sourcePath = context.get("sourcePath");
        String targetPath = context.get("targetPath");
        return new CopyCommand(sourcePath, targetPath, delegator);
    } else if (operation.equals("DELETE")) {
        String filePath = context.get("filePath");
        return new DeleteCommand(filePath, delegator);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner, more configurable way to create parametrized command objects on the fly (dynamically configure them, from context) that operate with different (number of) arguments?